# A situation where your friend or your neighbor offend you, that you wish to have no more interaction with them

Tags: expressions

I need an expression or a phrase—even if it is an idiom (to make it stylish)—commonly used by English native speakers to express a situation where your friend or your neighbor offend you so much that you are declaring to them in (a threatening way) you wish to have no more interactions with them. Or that they should know you are severing/cutting off any further relations or interactions with them.

To make it more clear, in my native language we say:

> "Ba ni ba kai!"

Whose English literal equivalence is:

> "No me no you!"

Which I wonder if say I so (the "No me no you!") could communicate such expression easily to English native speakers, could it?

Comment: Are there any problems with something more broad that doesn't have the longer lasting implications? For instance, "Go away" fits, but doesn't necessarily mean "stay away", although you could compound them to make "Go away and stay gone."

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think I might say this using this phrase:

> ***I'm done with you.***

NOAD lists this meaning:

> **be done with** give up concern for : *Steve was not done with her*.

while TFD says:

> **done with (someone or something)**
>   Finished with someone or something; no longer involved with someone or something.
>   *That group has been a really negative influence in my life, so I've decided that I'm done with them altogether.*

This can also be said as: *I'm through with you.*

Like the expression in your native language, these are succinct and abrupt expressions that can be used to tell someone that future interactions are over. But your literal translation (*No me, no you*) would not work well in English.

Comment: I'm not sure this carries the same inherent weight as the original. With the right delivery, it might carry the same weight; but just reading it in text, the initial impression that popped into my mind is "I am fed up and going to go away until I calm down or you stop being bothersome". Or, in some contexts, it could also be used as "you are now free to go", such as if you're helping someone who doesn't realize that you've finished what you needed to do.

Answer (score 31):

**"Dead to me"** is an English idiom in some regions of the USA (New England states, Italian-American maybe?), but it is easily understood even if the idiom is unfamiliar.

It's generally used as a single sentence:

"He is *dead to me*."

Once they are declared "dead" there is nothing more to say or do. "Death" is permanent.

It's not so much a declaration to the person's face (it's possible in a heated argument to say "You are dead to me!"), but usually it tells a mutual acquaintance that you are no longer interested in even discussing that person.

There's an *implied* declaration that any news to the contrary (that they are alive and doing ok) will be ignored.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dead%20to%20me

Comment: This can also be 1st person: "You're dead to me"

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Wouldn't that be 2nd person? And "I'm dead to me" be 1st? Or am I missing something here? It would certainly be _in person_.

Comment: @Arthur, since it is an idiom and not literal, it doesn't quite work that way. You'd maybe hear someone say "You're dead to me!" to end an argument before hanging up the phone for instance – but it's not usually what you'd say face-to-face since it's meant to be the final word, and the other person can answer back (thus ruining the whole my-enemy-is-dead fantasy).

Comment: You do hear this jokingly in person, "You use STRAWBERRY jelly on your peanut butter and jelly sandwich?!! You're dead to me now..."

Comment: HA! Make it "pineapple on pizza" and yes, I have heard this exact phrase.

Comment: It is a very old-fashioned expression though. You'd certainly read it in books, but I don't imagine many people use it these days (except ironically).

Comment: @Graham I wouldn't exactly call "dead to me" old-fashioned. From my experience I've only heard people use "dead to me" non-ironically when they're extremely serious about wanting said person out of their lives, given the obvious death connotations.

Comment: I heard it only after moving to NYC, so I've added some (anecdotal) regional info. It may be generational too, something an old person would say about a nemesis relative. For a young person to say it would be humorously coloquel, or somewhat ironic, like they know they sound like their kooky grandma.

Comment: @wetcircuit I can confirm it's broader than the NE US.  It's a phrase we're familiar with in the Midwest as well.

Comment: @wetcircuit Mid-Atlantic here, and no one would be surprised by the phrase, just surprised because it's no longer fashionable to publicly feud with people.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. "I'm done with you" does not have the same understanding of finality. It would just as often indicate temporary annoyance or frustration.

Comment: "You're dead to me, son. You're even more dead to me than your dead mother." From the film Zoolander.

Answer (score 15):

I think the simplest way to say this might be

> **We're through!**
>
> ---
>
> **be through (with somebody/something)**
>   *informal*
>
> - to no longer be having a relationship with someone
>
>   - That’s it! Simon and I are through.
>   - I’m through with you!
>
> from *[Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English Online](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-through-with-somebody-something)*

Answer (score 8):

You can end a relationship with someone by [**cutting ties with them**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cut+ties+with). The reason you cut ties with someone can be anything:

> To end or discontinue a relationship—romantic or otherwise—with someone or some group.

Example:

> After hearing his very offensive remarks about my father, I decided to finally **cut all ties with him**. I hope I'll never see him again in my life.

Comment: This is a useful idiomatic expression, but I don't think it works well in the OP's scenario. I can't imagine myself telling my neighbor, "I'm cutting ties with you."

Comment: Good observation but I don't really mean I would do that. I employed that to make the scenario easily understood and to add to my English vocabulary just in case or when making up a story in which such situation is meaningfully or reasonably imagined and justified.

Answer (score 3):

> **“I wash my hands of you!”**

This is an English idiom that means you plan to have no further interaction with, or responsibility for, another person or situation.

You can accompany it with a dismissive hand-washing gesture for added impact.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To "Part brass rags" is an old Royal Navy idiom for severing a partnership. (Messmates would keep their cleaning materials in a shared locker, but if a rift occurred they would move their stuff to another location.) Might be a bit too archaic for younger listeners.)

Comment: I have been speaking English for mumble years and never heard this curious and wonderful phrase! It would be great if you could provide a reference.

Comment: It is listed in here: [Royal Navy Diction & Slang - HMS Richmond](https://www.hmsrichmond.org/dict_b.htm), 3/4 of the way down

Comment: This phrase appeared a few times in P.G. Wodehouse books. That's the only place I've encountered it. He used a number of interesting English idioms.

Answer (score 1):

### The last straw

This expression is often used for when a series of problems becomes too much and change is required.

Car has many small problems:

> I sold that piece of junk. The last straw was that the door wouldn't lock.

This is useful in your situation in that the next time your neighbor is offensive you can say:

> That's the last straw! I don't want to see you anymore!

Answer (score 1):

**Shun**

For example:

> [Her once-friendly neighbors now shun her entire family](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2008-05-19/features/0805180131_1_neighbors-big-boy-bob)

*Chicago Tribune* 19 May 2008